# remove html code between two comments with perl

Tags: perl

say I have some html which from file which I save in string using perl which looks as follows

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td width="650">
    <!--MyComment-->
        <a href="http://myurl.com"><img src="myimage.png"  > </a>
   <!--MyComment-->
   </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
...
...
...
```

What would be the best way to remove the HTML code inbetween the two comments 
I was thinking of using HTML::tree perl module

Comment: There's also `HTML::Parser` you could take a look, but I don't know if it's good enough for your needs. Depends on what you want to achieve. Leave the document as it is except of the `a` tag? What if you have 3 comments?

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use a pull parser. Here you have an example with `HTML::TokeParser`. It uses two loops, the first one is used to find first appearance of your comment. It prints every tag it finds until there. The second one traverses all tags until second appearance of same kind of comment and doesn't print anything.

Content of `script.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use HTML::TokeParser;

my $p = HTML::TokeParser->new ( shift );
while ( my $token = $p->get_token ) { 
    printf qq|%s|, $token->[0] =~ m/S|E|PI/ ? $token->[ $#$token ] : $token->[1];
    if ( $token->[0] eq q|C| && $token->[1] =~ m/(?i)MyComment/ ) { 
    ## Here begins the comment.
        while ( my $token2 = $p->get_token ) { 
            if ( $token2->[0] eq q|C| && $token2->[1] =~ m/(?i)MyComment/ ) { 
            ## Here ends the comment.
                printf qq|%s|, $token2->[1];
                last;
            }   
        }   
    }   
}
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl htmlfile
```

That yields:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td width="650">
    <!--MyComment--><!--MyComment-->
   </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with [HTML::Restrict](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aRestrict), which removes comments by default.  The caveat is that with HTML::Restrict, you'd need to allow explicitly all HTML elements and attributes which you'd like to retain.  If you're just looking to delete comments, this is probably not the right module for you, but if there are other elements you need to remove while you're at it, it may be worth looking into.

Comment: this way sounds good too, i'll take a look .. html::tree can delete html nodes which is basically what i was looking for ..

Comment: There are lots of ways to get this done, so if you've already found something that works for you, that's excellent.  :)  Just wanted to point out this tool for going beyond your initial use case.